# Forewarding ports, specifically port 25565 not working

Tags: server, port, minecraft, forwarding

So, I have been setting up a server for minecraft using McMyAdmin and Ubuntu server edition. The port :8080 for managing the server is working fine with port forwarding, however, port 25565 for the server itself is not. Can I have some help with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure to make a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)  and check how to [Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forwarding ports is different for every different type of router that you have, and to a lesser extent, the operating system that you have. It's also different for individual applications. As such, you'll need quite a specialised guide.

I'd recommend checking out PortForward's guide on [forwarding ports](https://portforward.com/router.htm).

You'll also likely want a [static IP address](https://portforward.com/networking/staticip.htm) for this.

You may also need to allow both TCP and UDP traffic through Ubuntu directly:

TCP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp –dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
```

UDP:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp –sport 25565 -j ACCEPT
```

Save the changes:

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Obsidian Age, but it looked like the real problem was that port :25565 was blocked. I have it set to :8081 temporarily until I get his sorted out. Any idea how to unblock a port?

Comment: 'port forwarding' is essentially the same thing as unblocking a port. However, what you may be looking for is to open ports directly through Ubuntu. I've updated my answer to hopefully cover this :)